# Forcing gvim to open all files in the same window (using gvim with cscope)

Tags: editor, vim, cscope

I was wondering if anyone knew of way of making gvim to default to the behavior of opening all files opened by gvim into the same gvim instance.  I know there are parameters that could be sent to it by command line to force this, but I was wondering if there was something that that could be added to the .gvimrc file rather than a command line parameter.

The reason for this is that I'm using gvim with cscope.  So I'm setting cscope to use gvim as my editor.  However I don't know how to or its not allowed (probably the former) to force cscope to allow me to send parameters to the editor.

A solution to either problem would suffice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can really do this from your .vimrc or .gvimrc. By the time that file is being read you've already started a new instance.

If you can tell cscope to use `gvim --remote` instead of just `gvim` as your editor then you might get the behavior you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, any idea how to make it open in a new tab at the same time?

Comment: @Neonfirelights the `--remote-tab` flag should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use vim's cscope integration?

```
:cscope add /path/to/your/cscope.out
:cscope find s your_symbol
```

see `:help :cscope` and :help quickfix for details.

Here are my mappings:

```
" F11 and F12 to go to previous/next entry
nnoremap <F11>          :silent! cc<CR>:silent! cp <CR>
nnoremap <F12>          :silent! cc<CR>:silent! cn <CR>

" Shifted: go to previous/next file in entries list
nnoremap <S-F11>        :silent! cc<CR>:silent! cpf<CR>
nnoremap <S-F12>        :silent! cc<CR>:silent! cnf<CR>

" Ctrl-F11/F12 : jump through quickfix lists history
nnoremap <C-F11>        :silent! col <CR>
nnoremap <C-F12>        :silent! cnew<CR>
```